# jsf add and remove the items from onel ist box to another list box

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am new to JSF  and I wanted to create a small add and remove functionality to list box from another list box.
For example I have one list box and contains values A,B,C and when I select the value from list one and click add it should
be added to the right side of the list and should be removed from the right side list box and added bakc to the left side of the list box.  How do create the layout for that? Any sample code is available for that? I am using JSF primefaces. please find the attached screen shot.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "PickList" Primefaces feature is designed to fit exactly this requirement.
Take a look: [Primefaces - PickList - Showcase](http://primefaces-rocks.appspot.com/ui/picklist.jsf)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this one, builtin primefaces listboxes- http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/pickList.xhtml